# PHP Errors while connecting MYSQL with wamp and Android Studio

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to connect my phpadmin database to Android Studio using wamp server, however unfortunately I get the below errors in my php code and I have tried to use mysqli instead of mysql. could you please help?.

Error log

Errors

```
    <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-fatal-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DB_Connect::query() in C:\wamp\www\bradvisor_login_api\include\DB_Functions.php on line <i>67</i></th></tr>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
    <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>269136</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\bradvisor_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0894</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>310872</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>DB_Functions->storeUser(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\bradvisor_login_api\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>136</td></tr>
    </table></font>
07-17 11:39:17.449    6463-6549/com.bradvisor.bradvisor E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-17 11:39:17.473    6463-6463/com.bradvisor.bradvisor E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bradvisor.bradvisor, PID: 6463
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

DBFunctions.php File

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }


    /**
     * Random string which is sent by mail to reset password
     */

public function random_string()
{
    $character_set_array = array();
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => 7, 'characters' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => 1, 'characters' => '0123456789');
    $temp_array = array();
    foreach ($character_set_array as $character_set) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $character_set['count']; $i++) {
            $temp_array[] = $character_set['characters'][rand(0, strlen($character_set['characters']) - 1)];
        }
    }
    shuffle($temp_array);
    return implode('', $temp_array);
}


public function forgotPassword($forgotpassword, $newpassword, $salt){
    $result = mysqli_query("UPDATE `users` SET `encrypted_password` = '$newpassword',`salt` = '$salt' 
                          WHERE `email` = '$forgotpassword'");

if ($result) {

return true;

}
else
{
return false;
}

}
/**
     * Adding new user to mysql database
     * returns user details
     */

    public function storeUser($fname, $lname, $email, $uname, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
        $result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, firstname, lastname, email, username, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$uname', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())"); // This is Line 67 where it brings an error.
        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysqli_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verifies user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
        $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysqli_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $salt = $result['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }


 /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $result = mysqli_query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
        $no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: *mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\bradvisor_login_api\include\DB_Functions.php on line 67* FIX IT

Comment: could you please advise.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `mysqli_*` functions you need to pass the link/reference (object returned by the `mysqli_connect(...);` call) which you get when you create the database connection.

Query calls will look something like:

```
mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM ...");
```

Personally I'd recommend to use the OOP style of `mysqli` instead of the procedural.

Comment: No. Please don't ask people to write code for you here. If you need someone to write your code for you, I would suggest that you hire someone to do it.

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_query uses 2 parameters, but you only use one, you need to set $link parameter and $query, like this:

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City");

Check the manual: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
   mysqli_query at list Two argument pass 1 is connection string and 2 is query

for Example
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
 if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City") === TRUE) {
printf("Table myCity successfully created.\n");
```

}

Comment: Could you help, Line 67 is  $result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, firstname, lastname, email, username, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$uname', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");